# Can a Report be Created from the Subscriber Object; Or Data Accessed Another Way?

Tags: reporting, isv, data

Salesforce gives the ISV the Salesforce Edition of the Customer Org in the Subscriber object, and this data is available no where else. Any ways to access data from Subscriber other than the Object itself? Report? Or other tricks?

Comment: Perhaps if you told us a bit more about what you want to accomplish you might get more of a response. For example, what kind of reports do you want to create and what have you attempted to do up to this point?

Comment: I don't have an ISV edition, but two things to try:  (1) See if the Subscriber object is listed as an option when building Custom Report Types, and (2) Try to export this data using a custom query in Workbench or DemandTools.

Answer (score 1):

This data is only available through the UI. The object that holds the information you're looking for is called `AllPackage`. It cannot be described, queried, created, updated, deleted, or in any other way manipulated outside of the provided UI, which is to say, read-only access with searching capability.